# 16 Digit Validation using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, validation

I am trying to validate a text field to 16 digits only. How can I do this using JQUERY?
Here is the text field

```
<input type="card" class="form-control" id="card" placeholder="Enter Credit Card" name="card">
```

Comment: there are plenty of credit card validation scripts out there

Comment: i dont want it to be a crdit card validation. I only want 16 digits

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $.isNumeric(value) && value.length == 16 ) {
  // pass
} else {
  // fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pun in input maxlength="15"